# YUI: RTE: focus and blur events

Tags: javascript, yui, rte

Is it possible to get the equivalent of the focus and blur events that we have on other form controls for the RTE? That is, I would like to know when a given RTE gets the focus and when it loses it.

I see that the RTE supports lots of events (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/#events), but I don't see anything about focus/blur. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dav Glass answered on the YUI mailing list that at this point this is not possible. However, there are ways to emulate this, even if they are not perfect. More in [this thread of the YUI list](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ydn-javascript/message/40867).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone finds this question and is looking for the answer, Dav Glass poste an answer in the YUI community forums http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ydn-javascript/message/40867 .

Comment: Eric, thank you for adding this pointer. Dav is asking to add an RFE, so this is not yet a solution, but the discussion will continue on that group. Cheers! -Alex